# A free module of infinite rank with bases of different cardinalities

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, free-modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Is there an example of a free module of non-finite rank over a commutative ring with bases of different cardinalities?

I know the theorem for the finitely generated free module case that any two bases have the same cardinality.

Comment: http://webhome.auburn.edu/~huanghu/math7310/4-2.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, two free $R$-modules are isomorphic if and only if the cardinalities of their bases (i.e. their ranks) coincide. That also holds for non-finite cardinalities. In particular, every free basis has the same cardinality, such that one has a well-defined rank.

You can still have two non-isomorphic free $R$-modules of infinite rank by choosing two different infinite cardinals.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification!

Comment: This answer requires the Axiom of Choice (or something similar) it should be noted. Vector spaces can, in ZF alone, have bases of different cardinalities, although constructing such a thing is difficult.